# Calculate determinant of expression with given determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I need to calculate the following determinant.

Given $det(B) = \frac{1}{3}$

Calculate: $det(AB^{T}B^{-1}A^{T}B^{4}(A^{-1})^{T}(A^{T})^{-1})$

My solution:
$det(A \cdot \frac{1}{3} \cdot 3 \cdot A^{T} \cdot \frac{1}{3^4} \cdot (A^{T})^{-1} \cdot (A^{T})^{-1}) = det(\frac{1}{3^4} \cdot A \cdot A^{T} \cdot (A^{T})^{-2}) =det(\frac{1}{3^4} \cdot A \cdot I \cdot (A^{T})^{-1}) = det(\frac{1}{3^{4}} \cdot A \cdot (A^{T})^{-1})$

I don't know how to continue from here, I can't find way to calculate or eliminate both of A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall we have $\det(CD)=(\det C)(\det D)$ (see, for example, https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Determinant_of_Matrix_Product) and $\det C=\det(C^T)$ for any $n\times n$ matrix $C,D$;
if $C$ is furthermore invertible, then $\det(C^{-1})\det C=\det(C^{-1}C)=1$ and so $\det(C^{-1})=(\det C)^{-1}$.
Thus,
$$\det(AB^TB^{−1}A^TB^4(A^{−1})^T(A^T)^{−1})=
(\det A)(\det B)(\det B)^{-1}(\det A)(\det B)^4(\det A)^{-1}(\det A)^{-1}=(\det B)^4=1/3^4.$$